# Use a JSON file to change param in geo nodes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

actually im in the process of creating a atom generator with geo nodes which will be duplicated across the periodic table (like a 3d periodic table) using the loop node.
everything is working fine but i will have to change the params for each one, i found online a json file that contains all the params i need but dont know how to import it and use it in geo nodes
maybe with the help of python i can do that but im not exactly sure how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read json with Python. Find more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) or just search the web for "Python json".

You can also change node properties with Python. You need to find your object, then its geometry nodes modifier and then the node in the modifier's node group nodes, then you find the desired input:

[image]

You can simply change default_value for the inputs:
`bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"].node_group.nodes["Cube"].inputs[0].default_value = (2,2,2)`

Comment: Unfortunately, without knowing any context, it is hard to advice more. The way you automate the assignment of data to whatever it needs to be assigned to depends on details not provided, so you will have to figure it out on your own.